# Structuring tables of different content types? Single table with id pointing to the different tables of just having different content tables totally

Tags: sql, database

I have the following tables:

**photos**

```
    PHOTOS
    |____id
    |____user_id 
    |____url 
    |____time_uploaded
```

**events**

```
    EVENTS
    |____id 
    |____event
    |____start_time
    |____stop_time
    |____time_created
```

**comments**

```
    COMMENTS
    |____id 
    |____comment,
    |____user_id 
    |____content_id <-------------| uniquely identifies
    |____content_type <-----------| content
    |____time_created
```

The photos and event table share the comment table (ie the comments table contains rows for both photos and events. Because of this, the column `content_id` might have two rows with the same content_id but from different table (ie from events or photos). To differentiate them I added the column `content_type`

Recently I began to wonder if I should create a new table `contents` that will contain only `content_id` and `content_type` of all content type (whether events or photos). Then events and photos will have their own separate table which would then be joined to the contents table. This way I can have one content table and can add a foreign key constraint to the comments table easily because I have removed from the comments table the `content_type` column which can vary between events and photos.
Here are the new tables

**contents (*new*)**

```
    CONTENTS
    |____content_id 
    |____content_type,
    |____time_created
```

**photos (*new*)**

```
    PHOTOS
    |____content_id
    |____user_id 
    |____url
```

**events (*new*)**

```
    EVENTS
    |____content_id
    |____event
    |____start_time 
    |____stop_time
```

**comments(*new*)**

```
 COMMENTS
 |____id 
 |____comment
 |____user_id 
 |____content_id <-------------| uniquely identifies content and type
 |____ :)        <-----------| content_type now removed
 |____time_created
```

Should I continue with including `content_type` in photos and events tables like I've been doing or should proceed and create a single `contents` table that holds the content_ids and the content_type for these different content types, then when fetching data I'll then perform join on these tables? 
Please am looking for best practice to achieving a good database design because it seems the first method adds complications when adding a foreign key constraint. 
You might also want to know that I have more tables of different types too such as questions, posts etc.

Here is the relationship between the tables
[image: Table relationship]

Answer (score 0):

The relational model would not store content_id and type in the comments table.  The comments table should only contain attributes dependent on the comment.  You haven't shown how these tables are related. If you have multiple content types shared by both events and photos, I would have a separate table, a domain or lookup table of content types.  I'm not sure why the attribute time_created is in the contents table though.  What was created at that time?  If it's the photo that was created, time_created belongs in the photo table.  What's an example of a content_type?

Comment: Thanks @LAS, I think you slightly misunderstood my question. I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: In model A, it looks it looks like you have two entities stored in the comments table.  What's the cardinality between the entities?  Are there many comments for each photo ( 1 - M) or one comment per photo (1-1)?  Can many photos share many comments?  These are the questions to answer before you can determine the model?  I'm still not sure why content_id is in the comments table?  Give me an example of data stored in content_type.  If the arrow represents 1 to M, then you've got the photo as a child of the comment which doesn't make sense to me.